# Replacing a word or words in a sentence by word or words given by user

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace, user-input

I am trying to replace a given word in a sentence with an inputted word that the user gives. I'm having trouble figuring out how to replace word individually as seen in the code and example below:

```
def replace(line, word):
    new_line = ''
    for i in range(line.count(word)):
        new_word = input('Enter ' +word+ ' : ')
        new_line = line.replace(word, new_word)
    return new_line
def main():
    print(replace('the noun verb past the noun', 'noun'))

    main()
```

Output when running the above via the terminal:

```
$ python3 madlib.py

Enter NOUN : DOG

Enter NOUN : DUCK

the DUCK VERB PAST the DUCK
```

If the two supplied words were `DOG` and `DUCK`, I would like it to produce "`the DOG verb past the DUCK`".

Comment: What do you want to happen with words that appear more than once? And please add your observed and expected output in the question.

Comment: Please post your program output and input _verbatim_.

Comment: My observed output is in the image posted. As far as the output I would like to see is if the two new words entered were DOG and DUCK like it was in the image I would like it to produce " the DOG verb past the DUCK"

Comment: Please provide sample inputs and the expected output **in the body of the question**. Also, please keep in mind that while it may be _easier for you_ to post an image, it is _not as helpful to readers_, especially because they need to click on a link in order to see the result (though this might be edited shortly). You should just copy & paste the relevant console commands and outputs, formatting them as a block of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace()` `maxreplace`(third argument) to pass the number of replacements need to be done, something like this :

```
def replace_word(line, word):
    new_line = line     
    for i in range(line.count(word)):
        new_word = input('Enter ' +word+ ' : ')
        new_line = new_line.replace(word, new_word, 1)  # replacing only one match
    return new_line
def main():
    print(replace_word('the noun verb past the noun', 'noun'))

main()
```

This will result in :

```
>>> Enter noun : dog
>>> Enter noun : duck
>>> the dog verb past the duck
```

You can refer to [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) for more understanding.

Note : It is not good practice to use names for custom functions that are already identified by python interpreter. So, use `replace_word()` or something like this instead of naming your function `replace()`.

Comment: I entered this code and the output was "the duck verb past the noun"

Comment: Are you sure you are using it as is ?

Comment: @BrandonLeeOrnelas if this answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).

Comment: @BrandonLeeOrnelas Do upvote/accept as it may help others too.

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace(line, word):
    new_line = line
    for i in range(line.count(word)):
        new_word = input('Enter ' +word+ ' : ')
        start_index = new_line.find(word) #returns the starting index of the word
        new_line = new_line[:start_index] + new_word + new_line[start_index + len(word):]
    return new_line
def main():
    print(replace('the noun verb past the noun', 'noun'))
main()
```